# Converting values outside of range to NA

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, na

I have an age column: `df.age`, where some values exist that don't make sense in the given context.

How can I convert values that are outside the range of 18-100 to NA?

I know how to do it in R since there's a function for it, but is there something similar in Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html#pandas-series-where):

```
df['age'] = df['age'].where((18 <= df['age']) & (df['age'] <= 100))
```

Or with [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy-where):

```
df['age'] = np.where((18 <= df['age']) & (df['age'] <= 100), df['age'], np.nan)
```

---

Sample Frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'age': [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 100, 101, 102]})
```

```
   age
0   16
1   17
2   18
3   19
4   20
5  100
6  101
7  102
```

Sample Output:

```
     age
0    NaN
1    NaN
2   18.0
3   19.0
4   20.0
5  100.0
6    NaN
7    NaN
```

Comment: Doesn't the first one only select the values in the given range, instead of replacing them with NA? (haven't tried it yet)

Comment: No `Series.where` "Replace[s] values where the condition is False" Default replacement is `NaN`

Comment: Didn't know that. Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

Use `loc` with `between`

```
# sample frame
# df = pd.DataFrame({'age': [1,2,3,1,18,22,60,100,101]})
df.loc[~df['age'].between(18,100), 'age'] = np.nan

     age
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    NaN
4   18.0
5   22.0
6   60.0
7  100.0
8    NaN
```

Comment: This seems to not include the values, right?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.mask()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) together with [`.between()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) as follows:

```
df['age'] = df['age'].mask(~df['age'].between(18,100))
```

[`.mask()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) replace value (default to `NaN`) when the test condition is true.